# Laravel hasManyThrough getting through another model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this 3 tables. I would like to get the employee name who created the client

[image]

I have tried this

```
class LeadsModel extends Eloquent
public function researcher_name()
{
    $user = $this->belongsTo('users','id','user_id');
    return $user->getResults()->belongsTo('employees','id','employee_id');
}
```

But it returns an error:

```
"message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'employees.employee_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `employees` where `employees`.`employee_id` in (4))"}}
```

when I switch the id and employee_id, it does not return any relationship for users and employees.

Basically, I need to get the clients with the employee's name who created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming relationships:

```
Client belongsTo User
User belongsTo Employee
```

simply call this:

```
$client->user->employee;
```

---

Given your schema, here are the relations you need in order to get an `Employee` related to particular `Client` (through `User`):

```
// Client model
public function user()
{
 return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

// User model
public function employee()
{
 return $this->belongsTo('Employee');
}
```

then simply call this:

```
$client = Client::find($someId);
$client->user; // single user related to the client
$client->user->employee; // single employee related to the user
```

You might want to check if given relation exists first:

```
// just an example, don't write it this way ;)
if ($client->user) { // user is not null
  if ($client->user->employee) { // employee is not null as well
    $client->user->employee->name; // name = field on the employees table
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand this Jarek, can you please explain further?

Comment: Thanks again Jarek! You really have saved me alot of times! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [Has Many Through](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through) relation.

Add the relationship in your Employee's model called `clients`:

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Client', 'App\User');
}
```

And then you can use it like below:

```
Employee::first()->clients()->get();
```